# How to handle errors in AWS Invoke Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, error-handling

What's the best practice to check for errors and handle them using AWS SDK for JS in Invoke command for Lambda?

I'm invoking my lambda function, which throws and error, but I receive a `200` (like the docs says) but there's a special header that specifies that's an error.
How does AWS SDK (`@aws-sdk/client-lambda`) handle errors? Why doesn't it throw when there's an error header?
Should I read the response and verify if the payload contain a `errorMessage` key?

Comment: To check for errors, in your Lambda function, write log messages and check CloudWatch logs. You can write very detailed log messages that will inform you what is going on.

Comment: The HTTP header in a 2xx response that indicates an error is `X-Amz-Function-Error`. Check for that header.

Comment: Guys, I'm using the aws-sdk, I expect to have promise errors or something like that, why do I need to check headers? What does AWS Invoke does?

Comment: The docs are weak here or hard to find, no doubt about it. That said, you can test this quite easily to see what happens. A (JS) Lambda function throwing an exception will yield a result to the invoking JS client that looks like `{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"xxx","trace":"yyy"}`. In this case it won't yield a client-side exception. Other errors, such as infrastructure or permissions errors, would presumably yield a 5xx response that *would* yield a client-side exception.